# Webflux Router Immediately return 202 and continue processing

Tags: reactive-programming, spring-webflux, project-reactor

I am new to Webflux and trying to build an application using spring webflux. I am exposing an http post end point which takes a json and immediately return 202 and start processing the request in background.
This is not working as expected, I am getting immediate 202 but Mono Processing is not happening

```
    @Configuration
    public class StreamingRouter {
        @Bean
        RouterFunction<ServerResponse> streamProcessor(StreamingHandler handler) {
            RouterFunction<ServerResponse> streamRouter = RouterFunctions.route(
                    RequestPredicates.POST("/stream").and(RequestPredicates.accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)),
                    handler::process);
            return streamRouter;
        }
    }
    
    
    @Log4j2
    @Component
    public class StreamingHandler {
    Mono<ServerResponse> process(ServerRequest serverRequest){
      serverRequest.bodyToMono(Content.class)
                    .log
                    .subscribe(log::info);
      return ServerResponse.accepted().build();
      }
    }
2021-06-27 09:21:44.576  INFO 14076 --- [ctor-http-nio-3] reactor.Mono.OnErrorResume.1             : onSubscribe(FluxOnErrorResume.ResumeSubscriber)
2021-06-27 09:21:44.577  INFO 14076 --- [ctor-http-nio-3] reactor.Mono.OnErrorResume.1             : request(unbounded)
```

onNext is not happening after calling the subscribe.

If I change to return in the same statement it executes but 202 is happening in same thread after the processing.

```
return serverRequest.bodyToMono(Content.class)
                .log()
                .map(content ->  doSynchronousAPICall)                
                .then(ServerResponse.accepted().build());
```

I also tried `subscribeOn(Schedulers.boundedElastic())` but not luck.
I think I am missing something here. Please help

**Update**
As suggested I tried doOnSuccess but same result as map.

```
return serverRequest.bodyToMono(Content.class)
                .log()
                .doOnSuccess(content ->  doSynchronousAPICall)                
                .then(ServerResponse.accepted().build());
```

The problem I am having returning inside the same statement as its taking same time as the blocking call[doSynchronousAPICall] for sending a response as 202/Accepted. ie say 3 secs for responding 202. Rather what I am looking for is return immediately and continue with processing. Client is only wanted to know request reached.

Comment: try changing the `map`to a `doOnSuccess` https://projectreactor.io/docs/core/release/api/reactor/core/publisher/Mono.html#doOnSuccess-java.util.function.Consumer-

Comment: Thank You @Toerktumlare I will try and update back

Comment: Its not working same issue. in log its only printing onSubscribe() & request(unbounded). Some how the none of the 3 signals are not reached.[error/onnext/complete]

Comment: `in log its only printing onSubscribe() & request(unbounded)` i have no idea what you mean no `onNext` will happen if you are directly subscribing. You should not be subscribing in your application. The calling client is subscribing. Thats why i told you to replace the `map`. Update your code with what you have tried its VERY hard for us to know what you are doing if you dont show us.

Comment: @Toerktumlare   My requirement is expose a post as a streaming api[where client continuously pushing an id] , Server needs to get this id ,respond immediately that it is accepted[202], then continue processing the id with other api calls and some business logic. So I am converting the request to a Mono to process it in a reactive way.

Comment: and as i told you, replace the `map` with `doOnSuccess` and then you started saying that it is not printing correct? if i suggest something, you try it and update your post with what is happening so we can see what you have done, and if needed correct what you have done.

Comment: @Toerktumlare  Thank You for your response .I added an update to clarify. Problem is if I return in the same statement is making a delay in responding. Here client is not doing any process with 'POST' call response, Rather Server want to do the processing in another thread and in main just return 202. **You should not be subscribing in your application.** --> This is the part I am confused why we cant do that as its another mono we are trying to subscribe right. Hope this make some more clarity on the requirement

Comment: what does `doSynchronousAPICall` return, where is that code

Comment: @Toerktumlare could you please look into my question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77159199/spring-webflux-handler-function-sending-response-and-then-processing-request-in

Comment: @vinilpj how did you achieve this as I am trying also something same but not able to get required result